# assigning a value to the address

Tags: c

I tried the below program to make the pointer to point to a particular address and to store a value in that address.When i make the pointer to contain the value for the assigned address i'm getting a run time error asking me to close the program.
Is it not possible to assign a value to the address 0x6778.why is it so? In what situations does this needed? Please help me understand.

```
int *p=(int*)0x6778;    
printf("The address is:%x",p);
```

When tried to do *p=1000 i am getting the error.

Comment: Is there any reason you're trying to do this, or just experimenting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons why this could give you an error:

1. The address `0x6778` might not be part of this process's virtual memory -- it might not really "exist". You could read more about virtual memory, but basically addresses don't refer directly to physical bytes -- they have to be translated in a table, and that table might not have an entry for your address.
2. If it is mapped, it might be on a read-only page
3. If it's mapped and writable, it might corrupt some other part of your program, causing a segfault soon after.

In general, you probably can't write to an arbitrary address in a user-level application. Of course, if you're running a kernel or embedded system, ignore this answer, as it totally does not apply ;-)

Comment: :Thanks for the good explanation.I'm writing the entire question here.Embedded systems are often characterised by requiring the programmer to access a specific memory location.On a certain project it is required to set an integer variable at the absolute address 0x67a9 to the value 0xaa55.The compiler is a pure ANSI compiler.But i tried it on the visual studio-2008.

Comment: @Angus ah so this *is* embedded :-). But are you running on the embedded platform, or are you running your code in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm running it in visual studio.

Comment: @Angus Ah ok, then you won't be able to assign the value to that address, unfortunately. Are you just testing things out, or do intend to run it on a microcontroller?

Comment: :Yeah i'm testing how this works. But Als told me that even in embedded systems its not possible to explicitly assign a value to the address.He told that we can able to modify it in the kernel space.

Comment: @Angus It depends on the system. If it's a PIC or AVR you can write anywhere.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for explaining.I'm completely unaware of these things and came to know a lot from this disscussion which is= dont know.will read it.Thanks for helping me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

That address is likely not in your process's address space, so your program receives an exception from the operating system when you try to access it. You shouldn't be trying to use specific memory locations to store things... rather, use `malloc` for dynamic allocation, or put things on the stack.

Comment: Thanks christopher. Will use malloc for dynamic allocation of memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p=(int*)0x6778;
```

To do this, the address location `0x6778` should be a valid address location in first place.

An Address space gets allocated to every process, Your program runs in an particular process, If an program tries to access an address location beyond its address space then it will crash. Seems that is happening in your case.

Unless, you are sure that an virtual address location is valid for use by your program **DO NOT** access the address locations *explicitly*, let the compiler put the types in address space allocated to your process and return it back to you. To do that, the simplest way is to just make use of local variables with automatic storage or use `malloc` for dynamic allocations.

Comment: :Thanks for explaining clearly.I'm writing the entire question here.Embedded systems are often characterised by requiring the programmer to access a specific memory location.On a certain project it is required to set an integer variable at the absolute address 0x67a9 to the value 0xaa55.The compiler is a pure ANSI compiler.But i tried it on the visual studio-2008.

Comment: :If it is with embedded systems accessing and setting values for an explicit address is possible?

Comment: @Agnus: It is not possible to write explicitly to an address in an Hosted Environment. You can do so only in Freestanding Environment. A freestanding implementation is one that is designed for programs that are executed without the benefit of an operating system. So if your working in the Kernel space or Embedded enviornment, then yes it is possible.

Comment: :Thanks Als for clarifying my doubt.